# WinJS.BackButton sizes

Tags: html, css, winjs

I have this html tag which reffers to the backButton provided by the WinJS library:

```
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
```

I want to change its size. How can I do that? I tried using CSS by adding the ID "backButton" and font-size OR width/height properties, like this:

```
#backButton {
    font-size: small;
}

#backButton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

EDIT: Code added and a picture of what happens when changing the values of width/height of the button.

```js
// For an introduction to the Page Control template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232511
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/anime/anime.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // TODO: Initialize the page here.
            this.renderAnimeInfo(Identifier.file);
        },

        unload: function () {
            // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
        },

        updateLayout: function (element) {
            /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

            // TODO: Respond to changes in layout.
        },

        renderAnimeInfo: function (id) {
            // Path for the anime data.
            var path = "data/animes.json";

            // Retrieve the .json.
            WinJS.xhr({ url: path }).then(
                function (response) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        if (json[i].file == id) {
                            var animeData = json[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                function (error) {},
                function (progress) {}
                );
        },


    });
})();
```

```css
.right {
    float: right;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

#animeDetails {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#animeInfo {
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float: right;
}

#navbar {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}

#navbar .right button {
    margin-right: 4px;
}

#navbar input {
    width: 150px;
}

#details {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: justify;
    white-space: pre-line;
}

#details h3 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>anime</title>

    <link href="anime.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="anime.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="animeDetails"></div>

    <div id="animeInfo">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div class="left">
                <button class="left" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
                <h3>Back</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <button type="button" class="active">Details</button>
                <button type="button">Episodes</button>
                <button type="button">Characters</button>
                <button type="button">Staff</button>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="details">
            <div id="synopsis">
                <h3>Synopsis</h3>
                <span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When using the width/height properties, what happens is that the button does resize to the specified value, but the icon inside (which is not a background) doesn't. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgjCD.png

Comment: Don't use properties attributes on the tag itself, that behaviour is deprecated. But please show us the CSS you tried and I will correct it

Comment: I edited the post with the CSS.

Comment: Can you add all your important code or a working example to see what exactly happens and I will try to help u

Comment: Done. This HTML page works like an iframe, under the default.html. On the default you have other stylesheets, like the default one provided by Microsoft. You can probably find it on the web, but let me know if you want me to link it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have to set `display: inline-block` to `button` because the width of an element with `display: inline` (the default for `buttons`) is exactly the same as its content because it only takes up the space needed to display its contents so try with:

**With id selector**

```css
 #backButton {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="backButton" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
```

**With style inline**

```html
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block"></button>
```

Try to set the styles to child element `.win-back`

```
#backButton .win-back{
     /*---styles---*/
}
```

Comment: I think by default, the WinJS sets the backButton to inline-block. The result was the same as before, what happens is that the button gets smaller, but the icon inside it actually gets cut in half (instead of resizing to the specified size). I am sure there is the "correct way" of doing it by using WinJS, I just can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @user3492079 I added a new tip let me know if it works for you

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. How did you get to this conclusion? That changing the .win-back properties would affect the button? Did you find it somewhere? I searched the first two pages on google and couldn't find anything. I don't understand why applying the styles to the #backButton doesn't override the other styles. Anyway, thanks very much, I managed to resize the button by changing the width, height, font-size and line-height. Apparently, that's how they did on the default CSS.

Comment: I just checked out the DOM Explorer and inspect the styles of the button :).

Comment: I still don't get it why adding styles to #backButton doesn't work, but adding styles to #backButton .win-back works (even if you use !important).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given your button an ID. The CSS does not know what tag to link to.

```
<button id="backButton" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
```

edit: you may find the following reference useful [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I added the ID, tried the stated CSS above, since it didn't work, I removed the ID.